# reflection - Вызов метода с передачей массива

Tags: java, рефлексия

Имеется класс вот в таком виде. Тоесть написать `Foo` или `Bar` с указанием импорта не получится, только так.

```
Class foo = Class.forName("com.secret.Foo");
Class bar = Class.forName("com.secret.Bar");
```

Есть метод в классе `Foo` под именем `make`. Ему надо передать массив классов `Bar`. Как такое реализовать?

Если бы можно было использовать эти классы

```
Bar bar1 = new Bar(1);
Bar bar2 = new Bar(2);
Bar[] bars = {bar1, bar2};
Foo.make(bars);
```

А как с рефлексией?

**UPD**

Попытался сделать так

```
ArrayList<Object> ar = new ArrayList<>();
ar.add(bar1);
ar.add(bar2);
Class foo = Class.forName("com.secret.Foo");
    for(Method m : foo.getMethods()){
    if(m.getName().equals("make")) {
        m.invoke(foo, new Object[]{ar.toArray()});
}
}
```

Но таким образом я получаю ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method com.secret.Foo.make argument 1 has type com.secret.Bar[], got java.lang.Object[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что класс `Bar` выглядит так:

```
package com.secret;

class Bar
{
    protected final int value;

    protected Bar(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

А класс `Foo` - так:

```
package com.secret;

class Foo
{
    protected static void make(Bar[] bars)
    {
        for (Bar bar : bars)
        {
            System.out.println("Making bar: " + bar.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда извне (с учетом модификатора доступа `protected` у конструктора и метода) сделать это можно так:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class foo = Class.forName("com.secret.Foo");
            Class bar = Class.forName("com.secret.Bar");
            Constructor constr = bar.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class);
            constr.setAccessible(true);
            Object bar1 = constr.newInstance(1);
            Object bar2 = constr.newInstance(2);
            Object array = Array.newInstance(bar, 2);
            Array.set(array, 0, bar1);
            Array.set(array, 1, bar2);
            Method method = foo.getDeclaredMethod("make", array.getClass());
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(null, new Object[] { array });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на экран:

```
Making bar: 1
Making bar: 2
```

Comment: Ого, круто! Я что-то находил на enSO, но дальше создания массива не заходил. Не понимал как юзать `Array`. Спасибо :)